# Error no se puede convertir el tipo 'List en String' al querer retornar lista

Tags: c#

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult getInformacion(string cp)
    {
        List<Empleado> list = new List<Empleado>();
        Empleado item = new Empleado();
        EmpleadosEntities bd = new EmpleadosEntities();
        var queryEmpleado = (from c in bd.Codigo
                            where c.Codigo1 == cp
                            select new { c.Id, c.nombre, c.Fk_area }).ToList().Distinct();
        foreach (var x in queryEmpleado.ToList())
        {
            Empleado items = new Empleado();
            list.Add(new Empleado()
            {
                _Empleado = getArea(x.Id)
            });

        }
        return Json(queryEmpleado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    
    private string getArea(string id)
    {
        List<Empleado> list = new List<Empleado>();
        Empleado item = new Empleado();
        AreaEntities bd = new AreaEntities();
        var queryArea = (from c in bd.Area
                             join cd in bd.Empresa on c.Fk_C equals cd.Id_CodigoPostal
                             where cd.Id == id
                               select new { c.Id, c.Nombre, c.Fk_C }).ToList().Distinct();

        foreach (var x in queryArea.ToList())
        {
            Empleado items = new Empleado();
            list.Add(new Empleado()
            {
               _id_t = x.Id,
               _nombre = x.Nombre,
               _fkColo = x.Fk_C,
            }
            );
        }
        return list; //No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List en String'
    }
```

Porque me sale este error cuando intento regresar una lista:

> No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List en String'

Comment: Porque estas devolviendo una lista, pero tu metodo tiene como firma un string.. que querias devolver?

Comment: Necesito devolcer Id y Nombre

Comment: y entonces porque devolves un string? y ahi estas llenando una lista.. de cual de todos los objetos de la lista queres devolver eso?

Comment: @cosito lo que quieres es devolver 1 empleado cierto? que se compone de _id, _nombre, _fkColo? si es asi creo q lo que deberias hacer es a tu query es ponerle un singleOrDefault y retornar ese empleado, y cambiar la firma del metodo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es claro: tu método es de tipo String, por lo tanto **debería devolver un valor string.** En tu código, lo que intentas hacer es devolver una lista en vez de una cadena de caracteres:

```
private List getArea(string id)
```

---

Si en vez de eso, lo que necesitas es imprimir **un dato concreto dentro de la lista**, lo que te recomiendo es utilizar los atributos y pasarlos a string con el método *.ToString();*

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private string getArea(string id) -> signatura devuelve unstring 
    List<Empleado> list = new List<Empleado>();
    ... 
    return list;  // no es un string sino un list<Empleado>
```

Te recomiendo que en la clase de empleado añadas un método ToString , de esta forma al hacer el tostring de la lista llamaria al método to string de los empleados.

```
private string getArea(string id) -> signatura devuelve unstring 
        List<Empleado> list = new List<Empleado>();
        ... 
        return list.toString();  // string
```